# Is my movement tracked for hatching eggs while the screen is locked but the app open?

Tags: pokemon-go

Hatching eggs sucks. I'd like to hatch these eggs while I'm doing my daily running exercises. Will my movement be tracked if the app is open but the phone is locked? I ask because I attempted this with a treadmill, and I made no progress whatsoever towards my eggs.

Comment: When you say your phone's "screen is off" do you mean that in order to turn it back on you would need to hit the home button and unlock it?

Comment: Yes, the phone is locked. I will clarify.

Comment: If on Android: Relates to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273710/59161

Comment: but, you position wont move if you use treadmill.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately distance walked only counts via GPS and not pedometer, so running on a treadmill won't lead to eggs hatching.
Also the app does have to be open and the phone unlocked. There is a "battery saver" option in the in-game settings. This will dim the screen when your phone is up-side-down, such as in your pocket.

Comment: Unfortunately, when dimming the screen, it doesn't turn off the software buttons - so my phone would go to home screen as soon as I put it in my pocket.

Comment: I've heard from other players that putting your phone in my pocket with the screen facing away from your body is slightly less likely to press a bunch of buttons. I've had mild success with this as well.

Comment: I've been wearing a shirt with a chest pocket, I put my phone in there upside-down and haven't had too many issues

Comment: Verifying what @raumkrieger said. My G5 has software buttons, and as long as I put it in my pocket face-out by its edges, it seems content to stay running in battery saver mode.

Of course this exposes your phone's screen to possible damage, e.g. running into the corner of a table. If you have a case that has a flip-cover for your screen, you might be better off. I'm actually thinking of investing in such a cover, as I could just put my phone in my pocket screen-inward, and the flip cover would keep my hip from triggering the software buttons.

Comment: @DoktorJ Just be sure that your phone isn't able to detect if you're using a flip-cover and locks the screen. Some phones know when you open or close the cover to turn the screen on and off. Depends on the phone though.

Answer (score 21):

Your movement is tracked through a mixture of your phone's GPS and Pedometer. So running on a treadmill is not going to work.

As for 'locking' your screen, this will also prevent you from gaining egg progress. The app has to be active, and your phone can't be locked.

Comment: More and more sources seem to claim the pedometer is not used. Proof of this seems to be active tracking of distance with low quality GPS sensors whilst the phone is lying still on a desk.

Comment: @DavidMulder This is true. I have Developer Settings activated that my screen is never locked when the battery is loading: I went to bed, placed my phone on the table and in the morning I had around 4km egg-progress. This might happen due to losing GPS and reconnecting to it, the avatar "toggles" around in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The app has to be open to track your progress.

However, if you turn on the battery saver mode in the settings you can turn your phone upside down and the screen will dim, but it will still track your progress while wasting less battery.

Answer (score -1):

This app let's you lock your screen, put in your pocket or whatever and still play.  Has a battery save feature as well. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pokegoassist.pokepal.droid